# The mystery arguments passed by setTimeout in Firefox

Tags: javascript, settimeout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Firefox setTimeout(func, ms) sending default parameters to callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383479/firefox-settimeoutfunc-ms-sending-default-parameters-to-callback)

I have been wondering this for a long time. When I type in the following line in FF, then I get:

```
var timer = setTimeout(function () {console.log(arguments)}, 500);
```

`arguments` outputs an array with a random number in it, and this number is different from the value of the `timer`. When I try on Chrome, the `arguments` is an empty array.

Anyone has noticed this?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find that question. It is a dup.

Comment: Maybe so, but I found THIS one first :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout:

> Gecko passes an extra parameter to the callback routine, indicating the "lateness" of the timeout in milliseconds.